# Google Analytics ecommerce only tracking Paypal

Tags: magento, paypal, google-analytics

I'm having an issue with Google Analytics ecommerce tracking.  I've found numerous posts about this, but none of the fixes seem to apply.  We're on Magento 1.5.0.1, so all the GA code should be built in.  We also installed the Fooman GA+ module, but that didn't help this issue.  The tracking code IS showing up on the success page when viewing the page source, but it doesn't look right...no items listed.  If I view the list of transactions in GA, it seems that they are all the Paypal transactions but credit card or money order transactions aren't coming through.  We use Website Payments Pro for our Credit Card transactions, so ultimately it's all going through Paypal anyhow.

I did some digging around in the code and it seems that the "_getOrdersTrackingCode" function in Ga.php is where the problem lies.  I added some logging...

```
$orderIds = $this->getOrderIds();
Mage::Log($orderIds);
```

...and found that the majority of the time, **$orderIds** is empty.  Sometimes it isn't and that is when the tracking code works.

What's going on here?  Anyone know?

Comment: Here's some more info I dug up.  **GA/Model/Observer.php** in the _setGoogleAnalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageView_ function, it has this line: `$orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();`.  The _$orderIds_ array is empty when this fails, so whatever is supposed to be setting that before firing the Success event isn't doing its job.

Comment: I think I may have solved this problem, but I'll update this question when I know for sure.  We use a 3rd party checkout extension and it needed to be updated.  The controller that dispatches the "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action" event needs to send the order ids in version 1.5.0.1 but I guess it didn't need that in 1.4.2.0.

Comment: SUCCESS!  Looks like that was the problem.  I hope this info helps someone else in the future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed the problem.  We use a 3rd party extension for checkout and it needed to be updated for 1.5.0.1 compatibility.  The dispatcher of the *checkout_onepage_controller_success_action* event needs to send an array of the order ids as well.  This wasn't necessary in 1.4.2.0.  I updated the extension and it's working great now!  I hope this helps anyone else with a similar issue.

Comment: Wow, you just saved me from days of frustration! Thanks a ton!

Comment: absolute legendary fix :) I was following the same path as you were but not sure how long it would have taken me to realise an extension was interfering!

Answer (score 1):

Please note that this is an ORDER COMPLETE / SUCCESS event. You can't see the rendered code until you've completed a (test) transaction. On the order confirmation page, hit view source. In your `<script />` tag's you'll see some new push code if all goes well.

Yes, Brian, your code definitely lead us in the right direction. We ended up turning the PayPal checkout to `test mode = yes`, `debug mode = yes`. We're on 1.4.2. and this worked fine. Respond to this if you need help. If I'm alive, I will try to get back to you.